# UIResponder and multiple UIControlEvents

Tags: ios, uiresponder, uicontrolevents

Is there a way to call a selector for multiple UIControlEvents?

this doesn't work, but itl'll give u an idea of what i'm trying to do.

```
[self.slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderDidStopDragging:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside, UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
```

thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way instead:

```
// same selector for different events
[self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(selector0:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(selector0:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
// etc...
```

or you can use this one:

```
// different selectors for same event
[self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(selector1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(selector2:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
// etc...
```

Answer (score 16):

Just `OR` them:

```
[self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(selector0:) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchUpInside|UIControlEventTouchUpOutside)];
```

Comment: Is there a Swift version for this ?

Comment: Yes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24064650/how-to-pass-multiple-enum-values-as-a-function-parameter

Answer (score 2):

They are now an option set so you can use for: [.touchUpInside, .touchUpOutide]