# How to pass multiple enum values as a function parameter

Tags: swift

How would I do the following - passing two NSStringDrawing options as a function parameter in swift:

```
CGRect boundingRect = [string boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(280.0, NSIntegerMax)
                                                      options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading
                                                   attributes:options context:nil];
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Edit: In **Swift 3.0**:

```
let options: NSStringDrawingOptions = [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading]
```

---

Edit: **This is how you would use the options enum in Swift 2.0**:

```
let options: NSStringDrawingOptions = [.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, .UsesFontLeading]
```

---

Edit: **The issue [has been resolved in iOS 8.3 SDK Beta 1 (12F5027d)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS83APIDiffs/modules/UIKit.html)**:

> **Modified `NSStringDrawingOptions` [struct]**
>
> - From: `enum NSStringDrawingOptions : Int`
> - To: `struct NSStringDrawingOptions : RawOptionSetType`

You can now write:

```
let options : NSStringDrawingOptions = .UsesLineFragmentOrigin | .UsesFontLeading
```

---

After some research and and @Anton Tcholakov's "comment":

1. If you're targeting OS X 10.10, this is as simple way to do it:

   ```
   let size = CGSize(width: 280, height: Int.max)
   let options : NSStringDrawingOptions = .UsesLineFragmentOrigin | .UsesFontLeading

   let boundingRect = string.bridgeToObjectiveC().boundingRectWithSize(size, options: options, attributes: attributes, context: nil)
   ```
2. However, in iOS 8 SDK (in the current seed), there's a bug, where `NSStringDrawingOptions` is ported to Swift as `enum : Int`, instead of `struct : RawOptionSet`. You should send a bug report to Apple describing this serious problem.

Comment: what sort of a drawing options that would return? ) there's only individual ones, not their combination, so the result of OR operation wouldn't pass the "type check" i guess

Comment: Sorry, those should be 2 different options. But it wouldn't work neither. This is a bug.

Comment: @devmiles.com Looks like a bug in iOS SDK, definetely. :( Check out my updated answer.

Comment: I'm going to file a bug; anyone have an existing bug report number they want to share?

Comment: Is this still an issue in the new Beta 5?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. My bug report is still open.

Comment: In Swift 1.2, NSStringDrawingOptions is declared as RawOptionSetType also on iOS. No need any workaround.

Comment: In Swift 2.0 this is no longer true. Now most of enums conform to `OptionSetType`, now you pass the enum values with the same syntax of arrays `[.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, .UsesFontLeading]`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761996/swift-2-0-binary-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-two-uiusernotificationtype

Answer (score 21):

**Updated answer for Xcode 6.3:**

in Xcode 6.3 Beta (Swift 1.2) this is finally fixed, you can do it now like this:

```
let boundingRect = "string".boundingRectWithSize(size, options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin | .UsesFontLeading, attributes:nil, context:nil)
```

**For old version:**

It looks like a bug in current beta, for now I write Objective-C method and use it from Swift:

```
+ (NSStringDrawingOptions)combine:(NSStringDrawingOptions)option1 with:(NSStringDrawingOptions)option2
{
    return option1 | option2;
}
```

and call form Swift:

```
let boundingRect = "string".boundingRectWithSize(size, options: StringDrawingOptions.combine(.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, with: .UsesFontLeading), attributes:nil, context:nil)
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice. I would never have guessed that you could take an arbitrary integer from Objective-C, _call_ it an NSStringDrawingOptions, and get it past the Swift compiler.

Comment: I ended up making a constant in an Objective-C file and just referencing it from Swift. Hopefully they fix this soon.

Comment: Amazingly, this bug still exists (iOS 8.1, Xcode 6.1GM2).

Comment: Actually, iOS SDK 8.3, not Swift 1.2 fixed this. ;)

Answer (score 7):

Another solution, use `unsafeBitCast`.

Like below:

```
let options = unsafeBitCast(NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin.rawValue | 
                            NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading.rawValue,
                            NSStringDrawingOptions.self)
```

Answer (score 3):

in swift 2.0 that will be something like

```
theStringDrawingOptions = [NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin,
                           NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading]
```

see lecture wwdc 2015 -> 106_hd_whats_new_in_swift in 6 min

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 2.1 we may use,

```
calculatedRect = (text as NSString).boundingRectWithSize(bounds.size, options: NSStringDrawingOptions([.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, .UsesFontLeading]), attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : font], context: nil)
```

to pass multiple enum values for a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Can't seem to comment to akashivskyy's post (not got 50+ reputation), but this seems to work on my end:

```
import Cocoa

let drawingOpts : NSStringDrawingOptions = .UsesLineFragmentOrigin | .UsesFontLeading
let boundingRect = "test".bridgeToObjectiveC().boundingRectWithSize(CGSize(width: 280, height: Int.max), options: drawingOpts, attributes: nil)
```

Also if I Cmd+click NSStringDrawingOptions I see it as inheriting from RawOptionSet.

Comment: well, now you got your 50 points ) i'm using ios though and still having problems (

Comment: Not that familiar with Cocoa APIs if I'm honest. I just have the above in a playground and it seems to work. Maybe someone else can help further.

Comment: No, that doesn't compile on iOS. On iOS, it _isn't_ a RawOptionSet. That's exactly the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Swift supports C's bitwise OR operator, but the enum's values are now in a specific scope instead of simply being global symbols:

```
let boundingRect = "fpp".boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(280.0, CGFloat.max),
    options:NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading,
    attributes:nil, context:nil)
```

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work because:
Could not find an overload for '|' that accepts the supplied arguments

Comment: not sure what you've edited, the code itself has errors but the major flow is that | doesn't work with enum : Int

Answer (score 0):

In **swift 4.0+** we can pass multiple options like this, its working for me

```
let options = NSStringDrawingOptions(rawValue: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin.rawValue | NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.rawValue)

let boundingRect = string._bridgeToObjectiveC().boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: 280, height: Int.max), options: options, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 19.0)], context: nil)
```