# Pass multiple options to NSLineBreakMode in Swift 2.1

Tags: swift, cocoa, enums

I’m trying to pass multiple options for NSLineBreakMode in Swift. In Objective C this works:

```
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping | NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
```

Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24065414), I’ve tried setting options in a constant like this:

```
var lineBreakOptions: NSLineBreakMode = [.ByWordWrapping,.ByTruncatingTail]
passageExcerpt.lineBreakMode = lineBreakOptions
```

But I’m getting an error back that says:

> Contextual type 'NSLineBreakMode' cannot be used with array literal.

Is there a way to pass multiple options for NSLineBreakMode’s enum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSLineBreakMode` is an `enum` type rather than an `OptionSet` type (even in Objective-C). You can assign only one case.

In Objective-C the expression

```
 NSLineBreakByWordWrapping | NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail
```

works, but it sets the mode only to `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail` by "or-ing" the raw values 0 and 4, check this

```
NSLog(@"%ld", NSLineBreakByWordWrapping); // 0
NSLog(@"%ld", NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail); // 4
NSLog(@"%ld", NSLineBreakByWordWrapping | NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail); // 4
```

So the Swift equivalent is just

```
label.lineBreakMode = .ByTruncatingTail
```