# Swift: Pass multiple UIControlEvents to addTarget function?

Tags: ios, swift

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101108/uiresponder-and-multiple-uicontrolevents) shows how to pass multiple UIControlEvents in Objective-C, but how do you do the same in Swift?

The following attempts generate errors:

```
upButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(endVerticalButtonTouch), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside | .TouchUpOutside)

upButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(endVerticalButtonTouch), forControlEvents: (.TouchUpInside | .TouchUpOutside))

upButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(endVerticalButtonTouch), forControlEvents: [.TouchUpInside | .TouchUpOutside])
```

Comment: Option set, same as array

Comment: Just use `[.opt1, .opt2]`

Comment: @LeoDabus please post as an answer!